# Preview ascii files in file explorer (eg nautilus) like in windows 8 under Ubuntu?

Tags: nautilus, software-recommendation

Is there a filebrowser that features a preview pane to preview Ascii files and images?
Can I do that with nautilus?
I'm looking for something similar to the Windows 8 file explorer. There you can preview ascii files, images, pdfs, etc.

Here is an example from Win 8 file explorer:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dolphin has this exact feature, and with a lot of options. The size of the preview can be adjusted quickly simply by adjusting the width of the side panel, showing as much as the entire first page. Depending on the configuration, it can also preview music/video files.

Answer (score 0):

Both Nemo and Nautilus have preview functionality. In both cases follow the menu ***Edit*** > ***Preferences*** and then select the ***Preview*** tab. In Nemo the dialogue looks like this:

[image]

Tweak these settings to your liking. Previews are portrayed for text files, `.pdf` documents, images and videos (and possibly more).

The previews are shown as the file icons, therefore you must make sure the *Icon View* is set as default in the ***Views*** tab:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I would need a preview pane that displays the content of the file I clicked on. Having giant icons helps for previewing images but not for ascii files :(

Comment: It is probably better if you can make this preview pane requirement more explicit in the question with a sketch or a screen capture.

Comment: I added a screenshot in my question above...