# How to preview or 'peek inside' file from within Files explorer

Tags: nautilus, previews

In macOS, I think pressing the spacebar lets you preview the file's contents before opening it. Is there a way to do the same in Ubuntu? (i.e. quickly open and close a preview of the file)

I've seen [discussion of a preview *panel*, and installing additional software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721349/preview-ascii-files-in-file-explorer-eg-nautilus-like-in-windows-8-under-ubunt), but I'd like to use default software and not have my screen space permanently occupied by a preview bar.

Adding tags to this message, I see mention of Gnome Sushi and Gloobus-Preview. I will try to search more about these items.

Comment: I tried installing gloobus-preview as the top answer instructed, but the package wasn't located: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26187852/ Perhaps I need to add the gloobus-dev Personal Package Archive to the repository, but I am hesitant to add unofficial software: I am using this computer for work, so the less room for error, the better.

Comment: try sushi instead. It's from GNOME and better maintained, IIRC

Comment: Why does it say it's available in the Software Centre https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gnome-sushi/ but searching 'sushi' or 'gnome-sushi' in Ubuntu Software doesn't show it as a result? Is it because that webpage is for 12.10 Ubuntu, not 16.04 Ubuntu? Is this package now deprecated or obsolete?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-sushi says it's in Universe. See https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/158442 and try again